# Keep original distance between image and text blocks on screen resize

Tags: html, css

When resizing [this browser window](http://tests.markgarvey.com/), the text and image divs pull apart from each other, but I want them to maintain their original distance between each other (or close to it) when shrinking the browser. I've tried various fixes, but I can't solve the problem.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Write some come please

Answer (score 1):

what needs to be fixed, is this CSS property :

```
.slides img {
width :100%;
Height: auto; // problem is here
... 
}
```

You set value `auto` to the height, and `100%` to the width. So when you resize the browser, the width of images change proportional to the browser's width ..
To solve your issue, you should set `100%` to your height .. 
You will have this code :

```
 .slides img {
    width :100%;
    Height: 100%;
    ... 
    }
```

If you set `100%` to the images' height, theirs height will be `670px` in all sizes, because `.slides`'s height is `670px` in all screen sizes, so you will have original distance in all sizes ..

Comment: Thanks, Ali. That does fix the problem of keeping the distance between image and text div the same, but it breaks the proportional resizing of the photo...i.e., it remains the same height, yes, but gets squeezed in its width.

Comment: I'm not sure how to ask a question like this without getting flagged. My question included the problem I was having and the desired behavior. If I knew "the shortest code necessary" to show the problem, I'd probably know the answer myself. Should I have included the entire page of source code? I'm not trying to be a smart-alec, but genuinely curious. I want to play by the rules, as I appreciate the help available here. Thanks.